# Next page issues with scrapy python (json)

Tags: python, api, scrapy

I'm trying to feed postcodes from a list and is not working well (inside a class). Start_urls take sa1, sa2, sa3 as expected but pass only 'sa3' (last one) inside the def, and next_pages gets only 'sa3'.

This is my code:

```
Class OnthemarketSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'onthemarket'
    allowed_domains = ['onthemarket.com']

    postcodes = ('sa1'), ('sa2'), ('sa3')
    for postcode in postcodes:


        start_urls = [f'https://www.onthemarket.com/async/search/properties/?search-type=for-sale&location-id={postcode}&sort-field=keywords&under-offer=true&view=grid']

        def parse(self, response):
            data = json.loads(response.body)
            properties = data.get('properties')
            for property in properties:
                yield {
                    'id': property.get('id'),
                    'price': property.get('price'),
                    'title': property.get('property-title'),
                    'url': response.urljoin(property.get('property-link'))
                }

            pages = int(100 / 23)
            postcode = self.postcode

            for number in range(1, pages +1):
                next_page = f"https://www.onthemarket.com/async/search/properties/?search-type=for-sale&location-id={postcode}&page={number}&sort-field=keywords&under-offer=true&view=grid"
                yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

I want to achieve this result, if possible.

```
This is start URL:  ['https://www.domainname-id=sa1&view=grid']
This is next page:  https://www.domainname-id=sa1&page=1&view=grid
This is next page:  https://www.domainname-id=sa1&page=2&view=grid
This is next page:  https://www.domainname-id=sa1&page=3&view=grid
This is start URL:  ['https://www.domainname-id=sa2&view=grid']
This is next page:  https://www.domainname-id=sa2&page=1&view=grid
This is next page:  https://www.domainname-id=sa2&page=2&view=grid
This is next page:  https://www.domainname-id=sa2&page=3&view=grid
This is start URL:  ['https://www.domainname-id=sa3&view=grid']
This is next page:  https://www.domainname-id=sa3&page=1&view=grid
This is next page:  https://www.domainname-id=sa3&page=2&view=grid
This is next page:  https://www.domainname-id=sa3&page=3&view=grid
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create `start_urls` list and overwrite it again and again so you get only the last url. Instead you need to append to it:

```py
start_urls = []

for postcode in postcodes:
    start_urls.append(f'https://www.onthemarket.com/async/search/properties/?search-type=for-sale&location-id={postcode}&sort-field=keywords&under-offer=true&view=grid')
```

**EDIT:**

The complete code:

```py
import scrapy
import json


class OnthemarketSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'onthemarket'
    allowed_domains = ['onthemarket.com']

    postcodes = ('sa1'), ('sa2'), ('sa3')
    start_urls = []

    for postcode in postcodes:
        start_urls.append(f'https://www.onthemarket.com/async/search/properties/?search-type=for-sale&location-id={postcode}&sort-field=keywords&under-offer=true&view=grid')

    def parse(self, response):
        data = json.loads(response.body)
        properties = data.get('properties')
        for property in properties:
            yield {
                'id': property.get('id'),
                'price': property.get('price'),
                'title': property.get('property-title'),
                'url': response.urljoin(property.get('property-link'))
            }

        pages = int(100 / 23)
        postcode = self.postcode

        for number in range(1, pages + 1):
            next_page = f"https://www.onthemarket.com/async/search/properties/?search-type=for-sale&location-id={postcode}&page={number}&sort-field=keywords&under-offer=true&view=grid"
            yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

**EDIT 2:**

```py
import scrapy
import json


class OnthemarketSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'onthemarket'
    allowed_domains = ['onthemarket.com']

    postcodes = ('sa1'), ('sa2'), ('sa3')
    start_urls = []

    for postcode in postcodes:
        start_urls.append(f'https://www.onthemarket.com/async/search/properties/?search-type=for-sale&location-id={postcode}&sort-field=keywords&under-offer=true&view=grid')

    def parse(self, response):
        data = json.loads(response.body)
        properties = data.get('properties')
        for property in properties:
            yield {
                'id': property.get('id'),
                'price': property.get('price'),
                'title': property.get('property-title'),
                'url': response.urljoin(property.get('property-link'))
            }

        # pages = int(100 / 23)
        pages = 4   # int(100/23) = 4
        postcode = self.postcode    # always 'sa3'

        for number in range(1, pages + 1):
            next_page = f'{response.url}&page={number}'
            yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

**EDIT 3:**

```py
import scrapy
import json
import re


class OnthemarketSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'onthemarket'
    allowed_domains = ['onthemarket.com']

    postcodes = ('sa1'), ('sa2'), ('sa3')
    start_urls = []

    for postcode in postcodes:
        start_urls.append(f'https://www.onthemarket.com/async/search/properties/?search-type=for-sale&location-id={postcode}&sort-field=keywords&under-offer=true&view=grid&page=1')

    def parse(self, response):
        data = json.loads(response.body)
        properties = data.get('properties')
        for property in properties:
            yield {
                'id': property.get('id'),
                'price': property.get('price'),
                'title': property.get('property-title'),
                'url': response.urljoin(property.get('property-link'))
            }

        pages = 4   # int(100/23) = 4

        for number in range(1, pages + 1):
            next_page = re.sub(r'page=\d+', f'page={number}', response.url)
            yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is what I’ve done:

allowed_domains = ['onthemarket.com']
    start_urls = []

    postcodes = ('sa1'), ('sa2')
    for postcode in postcodes:
        start_urls.append(f'https://www.onthemarket.com/async/search/properties/?search-type=for-sale&location-id={postcode}&sort-field=keywords&under-offer=true&view=grid')


Unfortunately, it still takes the last one only ('sa2' in this case). I wonder if I've done something wrong.

Comment: Probably because it works for me. Se the edit.

Comment: You're right, it's working for all 3 postcodes but not complete.   It takes only first page from 'sa1' & ’sa2' but all pages from 'sa3', so for the first 2 postcodes it doesn’t reach the next_page.     Any ideas why?    Thanks again

Comment: @christian_bear It's because `self.postcode` is always 'sa3', see the edit. If this answer was helpful then please accept it.

Comment: I am very grateful for your time and knowledge.   The error I have is   "Ignoring response <400 https://www.onthemarket.com/async/search/properties/?search-type=for-sale&location-id=sa1&sort-field=keywords&under-offer=true&view=grid&page=4&page=3>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed"     I assume because it gets 2 pages at the same time - &page=4&page=3>.      Any thoughts? Thanks

Comment: My bad. I offered a solution with regex. See the edit.

Comment: You are the best. Brilliant. Thanks